# A trigger based on the value of a DataGridCell

Tags: wpf, binding, datagridcell

I have some cells in a datagrid and I would like to highlight cells in certain columns red when their value is 0. I'm not sure how to approach this.

I've looked at this question: [WPF: How to highlight all the cells of a DataGrid meeting a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761382/wpf-how-to-highlight-all-the-cells-of-a-datagrid-meeting-a-condition) but none of the solutions have worked for me.

With using style triggers, it seems that the triggers are meant to be applied on properties. When I do something like  nothing happens (I'm assuming because there's more to the content than a simple value).

With the last suggested solution I was getting a compile-time issue which seemed to be a manifestation of a bug that's been in VS for a while now: [Custom binding class is not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018039/wpf-custom-binding-class-is-not-working-correctly)

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to change the background color of a cell based on the value of a DataGridCell is to define a DataTemplate for the DataGridTemplateColumn with a Converter to alter the Background color of the cell.  The sample provided here uses MVVM.

The keys parts to search for in the following example include:

1: XAML that converts an integer (Factor) in the model to a color:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
           Background="{Binding Path=Factor, 
             Converter={StaticResource objectConvter}}" />
```

2: Converter that returns a SolidColorBrush based on an integer property in the model:

```
public class ObjectToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
```

3: ViewModel that changes the integer value in the Model between 0 and 1 from a Button click to fire an event that changes the color in the Converter.

```
private void OnChangeFactor(object obj)
{
  foreach (var customer in Customers)
  {
    if ( customer.Factor != 0 )
    {
      customer.Factor = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      customer.Factor = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

4: Model implements INotifyPropertyChanged used to fire the event to alter the background color by calling OnPropertyChanged

```
private int _factor = 0;
public int Factor
{
  get { return _factor; }
  set
  {
    _factor = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("Factor");
  }
}
```

I've provided all bits needed here in my answer with the exception of core parts used as
the foundation of the MVVM pattern that includes ViewModelBase (INotifyPropertyChanged) and DelegateCommand which you can find in via google.  Note that I bind the DataContext of the View to the ViewModel in the code-behind's constructor. I can post these additional bits if needed.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DatagridCellsChangeColor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:DatagridCellsChangeColor.Converter" 
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Helpers:ObjectToBackgroundConverter x:Key="objectConvter"/>
   /Window.Resources>
 <Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Button Content="Change Factor" Command="{Binding Path=ChangeFactor}"/>
  <DataGrid
   Grid.Row="1"
   Grid.Column="0"
   Background="Transparent" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
   IsReadOnly="True"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
      Header="First Name" 
      Width="SizeToHeader">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" 
                      Background="{Binding Path=Factor, 
                      Converter={StaticResource objectConvter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
      Header="Last Name" 
      Width="SizeToHeader">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the Converter:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using Brushes = System.Windows.Media.Brushes;

namespace DatagridCellsChangeColor.Converter
{
  [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(SolidBrush))]
  public class ObjectToBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      int c = (int)value;

      SolidColorBrush b;
      if (c == 0)
      {
        b = Brushes.Gold;
      }
      else
      {
        b = Brushes.Green;
      }
      return b;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using DatagridCellsChangeColor.Commands;
using DatagridCellsChangeColor.Model;

namespace DatagridCellsChangeColor.ViewModel
{
  public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
  {
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      ChangeFactor = new DelegateCommand<object>(OnChangeFactor, CanChangeFactor);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Customer> _customers = Customer.GetSampleCustomerList();
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers
    {
      get
      {
         return _customers;
      }
    }

    public ICommand ChangeFactor { get; set; }
    private void OnChangeFactor(object obj)
    {
      foreach (var customer in Customers)
      {
        if ( customer.Factor != 0 )
        {
          customer.Factor = 0;
        }
        else
        {
          customer.Factor = 1;
        }
      }
    }

    private bool CanChangeFactor(object obj)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using DatagridCellsChangeColor.ViewModel;

namespace DatagridCellsChangeColor.Model
{
  public class Customer : ViewModelBase
  {
    public Customer(String first, string middle, String last, int factor)
    {
      this.FirstName = first;
      this.MiddleName = last;
      this.LastName = last;
      this.Factor = factor;
    }

    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String MiddleName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    private int _factor = 0;
    public int Factor
    {
      get { return _factor; }
      set
      {
        _factor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Factor");
      }
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Customer> GetSampleCustomerList()
    {
      return new ObservableCollection<Customer>(new Customer[4]
                               {
                                 new Customer("Larry", "A", "Zero", 0),
                                 new Customer("Bob", "B", "One", 1),
                                 new Customer("Jenny", "C", "Two", 0),
                                 new Customer("Lucy", "D", "THree", 2)
                               });
    }
  }
}
```